# Increase space in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am trying to change the space between two words in NSString. But here the problem is the space should be "100 px exactly". I have gone through several links but nothing helped. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Like `"Hello World"` should be `"Hello   (100 px space)         World"`

I know two labels can solve this issue but I may end up using almost 25 to 30 label. SO I prefer using one label. I have tried `NSMutableString` also but doesn't workout.

Thanks

Comment: just split it into two strings and use two `UILabel`s unless you want to drop to the CoreText level

Comment: `NSString` does not hold information about graphical representation of characters. It's the wrong type of object for layout operations.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass the view and draw it.

Split the string and use drawAtPoint: method

Example,

```
[@"hello" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withAttributes:<#(NSDictionary *)#>];
[@"world" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 0) withAttributes:<#(NSDictionary *)#>];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two UILabel to implement this ? just change their x point

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
label1.text = @"Hello";
[self.view addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100)];
label2.text = @"World";
[self.view addSubview:label2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple tab inside your string according to your space need. For example

```
NSLog(@"Hello \t \t  world");
```